# How to determine the transfer function of the second order FIR filter?

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters

I need to find the transfer function of the second order FIR filter. I searched a lot in the standard textbooks, but I could not get the mathematical expressions and derivations.

I want that the zeros positioned at $z_{1,2} = r(w_{0})e^{jw_0} $ where $ r(w_{0}) = (1-b + b\cos(w_{0})) $ where, $ b \in [0.5,1] $, $ w_{0} \in [0,\pi] $

- How to find the transfer function if it is this kind of form? This kind of representation confuses me lot.
- How to determine the direct form and lattice form and their coefficients for such FIR filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How to find the transfer function if it is this kind of form?

**Assumption:** the zeros are located at $z_{1,2} = r(\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0}$ where $r(\omega_0) = 1-b+b\cos\omega_0$.

We can generically write the z-transform domain representation of a 2<sup>nd</sup> order FIR filter as:
$$h(z) = k(z-z_1)(z-z_2) = k(z^2-(z_2+z_1)z+z_1z_2)$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary scale factor and $z_{1,2}$ are the locations of the zeros.

Converting to the frequency domain by letting $z \to e^{j\omega}$:
$$H(\omega) = k(e^{j2\omega} - (z_2+z_1)e^{j\omega} +z_1z_2)$$

Now your choice of $z_{1,2}$ can be substituted in.

How to determine the direct form and lattice form and their coefficients for such FIR filter?

The direct forms pretty much given by the expression for $h(z)$ above.

To convert to a lattice representation, follow the steps below (based on [Lattice-Structure for FIR filters](http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/ahdrouss/files/2010/02/chapter_7_lecture_2.pdf)).  This notation is somewhat different than above, but matches that in the reference more closely.

Let $y(n) = x(n) + \alpha_2(1)x(n-1) + \alpha_2(2)x(n-1)$

[image: 2nd order lattice filter]

The output of the lattice implementation is:
$$f_2(n) = f_1(n) + k_2g_1(n-1)$$

Substituting for $g_1(n-1)$ and $f_1(n)$
$$f_2(n) = x(n) + K_1x(n-1) + K_2K_1x(n-1) + K_2x(n-2)$$
$$f_2(n) = x(n) + (K_1 + K_2K_1)x(n-1) + K_2x(n-2)$$

Comparing that with
$$y(n) = x(n) + \alpha_2(1)x(n-1) + \alpha_2(2)x(n-2)$$
gives:
$$\alpha_2(1) = K_1(1+K_2)$$
$$K_1 = \frac{\alpha_2(1)}{1+\alpha_2(2)}$$
and:
$$\alpha_2(2) = K_2$$
$$K_2 = \alpha_2(2)$$

Mapping this back to the original direct form expression we can make the following relations:
$$\alpha_2(1) = z_2 + z_1$$
and
$$\alpha_2(2) = z_1z_2$$